# How to put blank space between two specific characters in CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to add blank space between specific letters using CSS?

What I have:
UnitedKingdom

What I want:
United Kingdom

Ideally, I want to read the text using CSS and if I found "UnitedKingdom" then replace it with "United Kingdom"

Comment: You can't do this in CSS. CSS is a styling language that can do minimal computations. In this case, you should try to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `letter-spacing` property with CSS, and place the last letter of United (d) in a span with a class that makes it space out.

```css
span{
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>
 Unite<span>d</span>Kingdom
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some workaround using `attr()` and `:after` on CSS could work, but would be much better using Javascript.